# Django - Permissions to proxy model

Tags: python, django, model, data-migration

I create a proxy model from `auth.Group` model, that I want to apply `permissions` to it.

**proxies.py**

```
class InstitutionOwnerGroup(Group):

    # Gestores
    pk = 1

    is_superuser = False
    is_staff = False

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        permissions = (
            ('can_manage_institutions', 'Gerencia Instituições'),
        )
```

**data migration**

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.1 on 2018-10-14 23:30

from django.db import migrations
from horsy.apps.accounts.proxies import InstitutionOwnerGroup


def create_owner_group(app, _schema):
    InstitutionOwnerGroup.objects.create(
        name="Gestores"
    )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0002_add_admin_user'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_owner_group)
    ]
```

**Gestores model in admin panel:**

[image: Group in admin panel]

The given permission `can_manage_institutions` isn't been applied to model in data migration.

How to apply a permission by using django permission system to a proxy model inherited from `auth.Group` ?

Comment: As a general rule, "can someone help me" is not a valid SO question. Please re-word your question and provide solutions you have already tried.

Comment: I've change to a more meaningful question

Comment: I'm disappointed you deleted your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709917/nodejs-how-to-write-in-stdout-stderr-asynchronously.  I put a lot of work into helping you and writing that response and it covers ground that would be useful to others as a future reference.  Why don't you undelete it, accept the answer and then start a new question with a more detailed description of what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Also, the whole SO model kinds of gets less useful if authors just delete their questions after people help them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154). There is a [recently updated pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/10381/files) to fix it, so with any luck it will be fixed in the next version of Django.

In the mean time there are some suggested workarounds in the ticket above. The simplest seems to be to [manually create a migration](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154#comment:57) for an un-managed model that points to your proxy model, which will then trigger the appropriate permission objects to be created:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='InstitutionOwnerGroup',
    fields=[
    ],
    options={
        'verbose_name': 'Group',
        'managed': False,  # Make it unmanaged
        'proxy': True,
        'verbose_name_plural': 'Groups',
    },
    bases=('myapp.proxies.group',),
    managers=[
        ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager()),
    ],
),
```

Your mileage may vary with this - I'm not sure it is entirely safe to do.